# Couchase Node Js sdk connection

Tags: node.js, express, couchbase

I am trying to connect my couchbase server but i am getting warning msg when i an trying to create a connection instance on app.js on my express.js app.

Here is the app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const couchbase = require('couchbase');

const app = express();
const userRoutes = require('./routes/route');


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//COUCHBASE CONNECTION
const cluster = couchbase.connect('couchbase://localhost', {username: 'admin', password: '5121451214'},(err,cluster) => { 
    const bucket =  cluster.bucket('test_data_bucket');
    module.exports.bucket = bucket;
}); 



app.use('/',userRoutes);

app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);

console.log('Web Server is listening at port '+ (process.env.port || 3000));
```

Here is my AutherModel

```
const N1qlQuery = require('couchbase').N1qlQuery;
const data_bucket = require('../app').bucket;


function AuthorModel (){}

AuthorModel.getAll = function (callback)
{
    data_bucket.get('invoice_32212100000218', (err, res) => {
        if(error)
        {
            return callback(error,null);
        }

        callback(null,res);
    });
}


module.exports.AuthorModel = AuthorModel;
```

when i run node app.js getting this error

```
node:2410417) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'bucket' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

//RESULT AFTER CHANGES

connection.js

```
const couchbase = require('couchbase');

//COUCHBASE CONNECTION
couchbase.connect('couchbase://localhost', {username: 'admin', password: '5121451214'},(err,cluster) => {
  const bucket =  cluster.bucket('test_data_bucket');
  const defautScope = bucket.scope('_default');
  const defaultCollection = defautScope.collection('_default');

  module.exports.bucket = bucket;
  module.exports.cluster = cluster;
  module.exports.defaultCollection = defaultCollection;
});
```

author.js model

```
 const connection = require('../config/connection');
    
    const data_bucket = connection.bucket;
    const data_cluster = connection.cluster;
    const data_collection = connection.defaultCollection;
    
    
    module.exports = {
        getUsers  ()
        {
            const data = data_collection.get('invoice_32212100000218', (err, res) => {
                console.log(res);
            });
    
            return 'Hello from express';
        }
     }
```

GETTING THIS ERROR

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circular dependency warning is likely because you are exporting the bucket from `app.js`, requiring it in your model, which is also likely included somewhere in `app.js`, forming a circular dependency.

To fix this, I would suggest moving the connection code into a separate file, so that you can require it wherever needed in your models and routes.

**Important note:** If you are using the Node.js SDK version 3.0 or above, you'll need to call `.get()` on a collection level object, rather than on the bucket. You can easily just export the collection you need from your connection code. See the following example of a connection file, which uses default scope and collection:

```
// connection.js
const couchbase = require('couchbase')

//COUCHBASE CONNECTION
const cluster = couchbase.connect('couchbase://localhost', {username: 'admin', password: '5121451214'},(err,cluster) => {
  const bucket =  cluster.bucket('test_data_bucket');
  const defautScope = bucket.scope('_default');
  const defaultCollection = defautScope.collection('_default')

  module.exports.bucket = bucket;
  module.exports.cluster = cluster;
  module.exports.defaultCollection = defaultCollection;
});
```

You can then easily require `connection.js` in your model and obtain bucket, cluster, or collection level objects as needed:

```
const connection = require('../connection');

const data_bucket = connection.bucket;
const data_cluster = connection.cluster;
const data_collection = connection.defaultCollection;
```

Comment: thanks i have updated the post by doing the changes you recommended but this time getting new issue can you please check  :)

Comment: the same get method when i call inside the connection file before exporting the default collection works fine

Comment: Try moving `const data_collection = connection.defaultCollection;` inside of your `getUsers()` function

Comment: It worked Thanks :)

Comment: is there any way to avoid this in every method const data_collection = connection.defaultCollection